# QLPreviewController canPreviewItem doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, excel, qlpreviewcontroller

It seems that QLPreViewController's method +canPreviewItem doesn't work.

I've under currentAttachment value path to xls document, but it's xlsx document.

```
if (![QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.currentAttachment]])
{
  NSLog(@"Can't Preview Item");
}
```

The methods returns YES, but preview is not generated.

So it's xlsx file saved as xls. And i'm trying to understand can I preview it or not, if not I'm trying to preview xlsx file etc.

But always it says that I can.

Comment: If it is an `xlsx` file, save it as an `xlsx` file and not an `xls` file. Those are two different kinds of files. `xls` is a binary file while `xlsx` is a zip file full of xml files.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand that, but problem that this broken files are coming to the app (exchange attachment), and before saving them to the system, I can assume only by filename that it's xls.

Comment: Anyway, problem is solved, I'll add it later.

Answer (score -1):

try `if(![QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:myPreviewItem.currentPreviewItem])
{
   NSLog(@"Can't preview item");`